# Como renomear o nome da coluna Tabela SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Quero renomear o nome da coluna via SQL. Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
ALTER TABLE nomes_clientes 
RENAME COLUMN primeiro_nome TO nome, 
RENAME COLUMN segundo_nome TO sobrenome;
```

Mas dessa forma não está funcionando.

Comment: Em qual banco de dados? Cada um é diferente

Comment: O banco de dados é o MySQL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Precisa redefinir todas características da coluna, assim:

```
ALTER TABLE nomes_clientes 
    CHANGE primeiro_nome nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
    CHANGE segundo_nome sobrenome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/RenameColumn.sql).

Answer (score 8):

Assim como @Maniero comentou irá depender do banco que você esta utilizando, mas para esses três (Oracle, PostgreSQL e MySQL) é da seguinte forma:

**Oracle**

```
ALTER TABLE T_CLASSE_SOCIAL
RENAME COLUMN TESTE TO  TESTE_NOVO;
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
ALTER TABLE distribuidores RENAME COLUMN endereco TO cidade;
```

**MySQL**

```
ALTER TABLE tabela_exemplo CHANGE id_exemplo novo_id_exemplo integer(5) unsigned;
```

Referencias:
[MySQL](https://eduardopereira.pt/2011/03/renomear-tabela-ou-coluna-em-mysql/) |
[PostgreSQL](http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg80/sql-altertable.html) |
[Oracle](http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-a-instrucao-alter-table-no-oracle/25186)

Comment: Nesse caso de MySQL,esse código não estaria mudando o nome da tabela ao invés do nome da coluna?

Comment: @Christian, equivoco meu, ajustei a resposta para os comandos corretos

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta:

**SQLServer**

```
sp_RENAME '[Tabela.NomeColuna]', '[NovoNomeColuna]' , 'COLUMN'
```

Neste banco, é utilizado uma sp pronta. Lembrando que é preciso utilizar o `exec` para executar a procedure. O terceiro parâmetro 'COLUMN' é necessário para o caso em questão, que é renomear uma coluna. Exemplo:

```
exec sp_RENAME 
          'Pessoa.codPessoa',
          'codPessoaAlterada',
          'COLUMN'
```

Para mais detalhes de utilização da SP:

Referências: [SQLServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188351(v=sql.120).aspx/)